# How do I create embossed borders using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, border, emboss

Some GUIs use boxes with embossed borders to group widgets.

How do I create this look with HTML and CSS?

*An embossed border is one that creates the illusion that an element comes forward out of the page in 3D. It is often created by making the top and left border lighter and the bottom and right border darker.*

Comment: Do you have a reference, example, code you've tried, problem you are having, or a question?

Comment: is not really a question, you can give us an example?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Have you looked at the source for these websites that you mention? Is there an issue with reusing this code in your own design?

Comment: Have you tried different border styles of border-style CSS element?

Comment: The question is in the title. I didn't think simple questions like this bore repeating.

Comment: @Wesley Murch, @Piskvor, @Nick Berardi, @Neil Knight, @trashgod: 
Well you guys are certainly quick on the trigger. If you don't read the question or forgot the question after reading the other two sentences, I can't help you (and where did I ever mention a website?). This can't be this site's philosophy.

Comment: @Wesley:
GUIs grouping elements are very common and IMO don't need an example. The question is the title. Is anything wrong with it? Surely you just have overlooked it.
@red eyes dev:
Why do you think this is not a question? Have you read the title? The example: pick any GUI with input widgets.
@BonT:
Have you read the question? What is not to understand? I don't mention any website, thus I cannot reuse any code.
@mohang: 
no, I did not think to look into that. Thank you.

Comment: My solution: https://codepen.io/Belyash/post/css-border-emboss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most GUIs I see use a style similar to CSS's `border-style: groove` for group boxes.

If you need to use a group box for your HTML forms, use `<fieldset>` with `<legend>` for the group label.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a few methods, especially with modern browsers.

The simplest is light/dark borders (increase pixels for a chunkier look):

```
.box {
  border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
  border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #777 1px solid;
  border-left: #777 1px solid;
}
```

For anything more complicated then background images can be used on the box. This provides the best browser compatibility. The [All-Expandable Box](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-the-all-expandable-box) has a good demo.

With CSS3 you can add rounded corners, drop shadows and all sorts of effects.

Also if you're using jQuery elements in widget boxes, then the [jQuery UI pack](http://jqueryui.com/)s come with some nice skins and easy grouping/boxes.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have the box's border embossed, not the box.

Comment: For a code-only solution you can embed many divs inside each other creating a gradient-like border effect. Or use background images as I suggested

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [the `<fieldset>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp).

> Definition and Usage
>
> The  tag is used to
>   logically group together elements in a
>   form.
>
> The  tag draws a box around
>   the related form elements.
>
> The  tag defines a caption for
>   the fieldset element.

Comment: Thanks. While it does not look much better than `border-style:groove;` saves manual styling of a couple of divs. Can be styled with `border-radius`.

Answer (score -2):

One of the various [border-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-style-properties) value other than "solid", "dotted" and "dashed" will probably give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked into that. The style theoretically does what I want, but it does not look real. And it does not render so nicely in Firefox and Chrome (dark rectangle overlayed by light rectangle with slight offset to bottom right).

Comment: Forgot: `groove`. Needs at least a width of `2px` (can width be omitted?).